# lvlc-qt missing compilation error

Tags: c++, qt, libvlc

I'm trying to make `demo-player` work from [vlc github](https://github.com/ntadej/vlc-qt), I load the `pro` file, specify the *supposed* directory of the `vlc-qt` lib (I've tried a lot a directories btw) but still no way to get things done. I've tried on both `Ubuntu`and `Mac Os`... Here's my pro file:

```
TARGET      = demo-player
TEMPLATE    = app

QT          += core gui

SOURCES     += main.cpp\
               DemoPlayer.cpp

HEADERS     += DemoPlayer.h

FORMS       += DemoPlayer.ui

# Edit below for custom library location
LIBS     += -L/home/VBB/Documents/vlc-2.0.7/lib/ -lvlc-qt -lvlc-qt-widgets
INCLUDEPATH += /home/VBB/Documents/vlc-2.0.7/include/ \
            /home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/src/core/
```

and the compilation message

> > /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvlc-qt
> >     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvlc-qt-widgets

by the way on `Ubuntu` I've tried

```
sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev
```

but it ain't change nothing.

**edit :**
If this can help

```
VBB@VBB-VirtualBox:~$ sudo find / -name "libvlc-qt*"
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/pkgconfig/libvlc-qt.pc.in
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/debian/libvlc-qt-get-orig-source
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/debian/libvlc-qt-core0.dirs
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/debian/libvlc-qt-core0.install
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/debian/libvlc-qt-dev.dirs
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/debian/libvlc-qt-widgets0.dirs
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/debian/libvlc-qt-widgets0.install
/home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/debian/libvlc-qt-dev.install
```

Comment: can you try `locate libvlc-qt-widgets.a`?

Comment: `vbb@vbb-VirtualBox:~$ locate libvlc-qt-widgets.a
vbb@vbb-VirtualBox:~$` seems missing

Comment: hmm.. google is failing me this time.. a rare occasion

Comment: That's the same reason I post here :)

Comment: Does my last edit show some missed step?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava Nop, I switched for `FFMPEG` which is very powerful and lighter than libvlc

Comment: @Samoth what did you do exactly?

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava let's switch to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46500/lvlc-qt-missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to specify after -L is the location of the following two .so files:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/vlc-test/vlc-qt/build$ find -iname \*.so
./src/widgets/libvlc-qt-widgets.so
./src/core/libvlc-qt.so
```

Normally you compile those libraries, by following this section in README.md:

```
    Compilation
-----------
    $ mkdir build
    $ cd build
    $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=prefix
    $ make
```

Comment: I dont have thoses *.so files you're talking about and I would like to compile my project thanks to `Qt`

Comment: You have to compile those libraries first, because those are the libraries you are trying to link your binary against! 
Your linker/loader reports those errors, because you don't have those libraries! 

Go to the /home/VBB/Documents/code/vlc-qt/ directory and execute those commands that I have written... All of those, that are under "Compilation", and that should compile those libraries for you.

Comment: Ok, I follow you advice `sudo apt-get install cmake` then `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=prefix` and it throw that the cmake version is too old

Comment: In the dependencies section it states:
- cmake >= 2.8.6
So you got to have at least 2.8.6
Ubuntu precise comes with 2.8.7 already, sou I suspect you must have lucid or older. You will have to update it manually. First result from google:
http://pgpz.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/update-cmake-from-ubuntu-1004.html

Comment: That supposed to have  
[2.8.7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/cmake) available.
but, try `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install cmake`
after that, if for some weird reason `cmake -version` would still report older than 2.8.6, then you will have to do download and install the package (first link in this comment) or do the manual update (link in my previous comment).